# Erro ao pegar dados do tipo Time do banco de dados

Tags: java, mysql, time

Estou fazendo uma consulta porém está dando erro quando tento pegar valores do tipo Time. Esse é o erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time
>   '13:00:00.000' in column 5

A linha que está disparando a exceção é essa:

```
linha.setHoraInicial(resultado.getTime("hora_inicio"));
```

Salvo a hora no banco de tal maneira:

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            java.sql.Time timeValue = new java.sql.Time(dateFormat.parse(txtHoraInicial.getText()).getTime());
            System.out.println("Time: " + timeValue);
            c.setHoraInicial(timeValue);
```

E faço isso no método salvar que fica no DAO:

```
comando.setTime(4, a.getHoraInicial());
```

E esse é o `StackTrace` completo:

> java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time
>   '13:00:00.000' in column 5    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimeFromBytes(ResultSet.java:6164)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTimeInternal(ResultSet.java:6198)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTime(ResultSet.java:5779)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getTime(ResultSet.java:5814)     at
>   com.agenda.dao.AgendaDAO.buscar(AgendaDAO.java:84)    at
>   com.agenda.view.FrmAgendaController.atualizarNome(FrmAgendaController.java:138)
>     at
>   com.agenda.view.FrmAgendaController.init(FrmAgendaController.java:127)
>     at
>   com.agenda.view.FrmAgendaController.initialize(FrmAgendaController.java:83)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)     at
>   com.agenda.view.Agenda.start(Agenda.java:22)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$53/681110827.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/355629945.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1296242029.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1915503092.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Qual o tipo do objeto "resultado"?

Comment: Meu caro, qual o tipo desse campo 'horaInicial'? Seria um Date ou um String? Se puder colocar mais detalhes, ajudaria.

Comment: O tipo é `java.sql.Time`

Comment: Consigo incluir os valores perfeitamente no banco, porém na hora de fazer a consulta da esse erro

Comment: Me corrija se eu estiver errado, mas o método `getTime()` não aceita nenhum tipo de argumento. Veja: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime() Você não quis usar o `setTime()`?

Comment: @Math o `getTime` que ele se refere é, provavelmente, o do `ResultSet`, já que ele está recuperando dados de uma base

Comment: Isso, eu estou tentando recuperar os dados.

Comment: @Techies qual o tipo de dado na base de dados? Fiz um teste simples aqui e funcionou, então considere incluir mais informação, com a *stack trace* completa e a forma como você salva os dados (como seta o parâmetro no *statement*), se possível mostre como a data está persistida na base

Comment: Estou usando MySQL, Eu não estou salvando a data apenas a hora. Eu inclui um trecho de como eu seto a Hora pra que ela possa ser salva no banco. Vou adicionar o stack trace na pergunta

Comment: Editei a pergunta coloquei como eu salvo a hora e o StackTrace completo

Comment: @Techies é cara, de forma simples aqui funcionou, então não consigo te ajudar =/ De toda forma obrigado

Comment: Não seria pq vc está usando a hora `13` quando na verdade seu banco espera `1 p.m.`?

Comment: Não sei, pois estou conseguindo salvar a hora no banco.

Comment: Olha como está o banco: http://i.stack.imgur.com/V7tCT.png

Comment: Eu fiz uns testes e mudei tudo pra `Int` menos o tipo `Time` do campo no banco de dados. Quando eu mudo pra `Int` eu consigo recuperar porém só vem a hora, por exemplo se eu tenho `13:50:00.000` só vem o `13` eu gostaria que viesse os segundos também.

Comment: Você não consegue alterar e trabalhar com timeStamp? quando você fosse recuperar era só usar um Format no seu time e trabalhar como desejar... @Techies

Comment: Não tentei com TimeStamp ainda, tenho que alterar o banco e as variáveis do modelo que recebem horas para TimeStamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema Resolvido, no banco de dados alterei o `Default` da hora para `00:00:00` dessa maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que fiz isso funcionou, antes o formato da data como esse: `13:00:00.000`